# Datatable version 1.10.21 is stuck on 'processing...' in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: json, asp.net-core, datatables, server-side

I am using `Datatable 1.10.21` in `ASP.NET Core 3.1` and I am stuck on ***'processing...'***. I am catching exceptions should they occur but so far I haven't seen any exceptions. For reasons unknown to me, database records are not shown.

Could you spare a moment and take a closer look at my code to determine where I am getting it wrong and point it out. I appreciate your time and effort to solving this issue.

Here is my code:

**My HTML Table:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Users>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Model Class:**

```
public class Users
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Datatable Initializer:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable(
        {
            // ServerSide Setups
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,

            // Paging Setups
            paging: true,

            // Searching Setups
            searching: { regex: true },

            // Ajax Filter
            ajax: {
                url: "/Home/Data",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: function (d) {
                    return JSON.stringify(d);
                }
            },
            // columns setups
            columns: [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "firstname" },
                { data: "lastname" },
                { data: "country" },
                { data: "gender" },
                { data: "age" }
            ]
        });
});
```

**Getting data as JSON:**

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Data(DataTablesResult tableParams)
        {
            try
            {
                var query = context.AspNetUsers.AsQueryable();

                var totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

                if (tableParams.Search != null)
                    query = query.Where(c => c.FirstName.Contains(tableParams.Search.Value)
                    || c.LastName.Contains(tableParams.Search.Value));
                //Other search queries goes here

                if (tableParams.Order.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (tableParams.Order[0].Dir == "asc")
                        query = query.OrderBy(c => EF.Property<string>(c, tableParams.Columns[tableParams.Order[0].Column].Name));
                    else
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(c => EF.Property<string>(c, tableParams.Columns[tableParams.Order[0].Column].Name));
                }
                //In this example multi order is disabled so we can order by any column dynamically

                var result = await query.AsNoTracking().Select(E => new { Count = query.Count(), E = E }).Skip(tableParams.Start).Take(tableParams.Length).ToListAsync();
                var pureData = result.Select(E => E.E);

                if (result.Count == 0)
                    return Ok(new { tableParams.Draw, recordsTotal = 0, recordsFiltered = 0, data = Enumerable.Empty<string>() });

                return Ok(new { tableParams.Draw, recordsTotal = totalCount, recordsFiltered = result.Select(c => c.Count).FirstOrDefault(), data = pureData });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();

                throw;
            }
        }
```

**Datatable ModelBinder Class:**

```
public class DataTableModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;

            // Retrieve request data
            var draw = Convert.ToInt32(request.Query["draw"]);
            var start = Convert.ToInt32(request.Query["start"]);
            var length = Convert.ToInt32(request.Query["length"]);

            // Search
            var search = new Search
            {
                Value = request.Query["search[value]"],
                Regex = Convert.ToBoolean(request.Query["search[regex]"])
            };

            // Order
            var o = 0;
            var order = new List<ColumnOrder>();
            while (!StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Query["order[" + o + "][column]"]))
            {
                order.Add(new ColumnOrder
                {
                    Column = Convert.ToInt32(request.Query["order[" + o + "][column]"]),
                    Dir = request.Query["order[" + o + "][dir]"]
                });
                o++;
            }

            // Columns
            var c = 0;
            var columns = new List<Column>();
            while (!StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Query["columns[" + c + "][name]"]))
            {
                columns.Add(new Column
                {
                    Data = request.Query["columns[" + c + "][data]"],
                    Name = request.Query["columns[" + c + "][name]"],
                    Orderable = Convert.ToBoolean(request.Query["columns[" + c + "][orderable]"]),
                    Searchable = Convert.ToBoolean(request.Query["columns[" + c + "][searchable]"]),
                    Search = new Search
                    {
                        Value = request.Query["columns[" + c + "][search][value]"],
                        Regex = Convert.ToBoolean(request.Query["columns[" + c + "][search][regex]"])
                    }
                });
                c++;
            }

            var result = new DataTablesResult
            {
                Draw = draw,
                Start = start,
                Length = length,
                Search = search,
                Order = order,
                Columns = columns
            };

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**DtParameters:**

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DataTableModelBinder))]
    public class DataTablesResult
    {
        public int Draw { get; set; }
        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public Search Search { get; set; }
        public List<ColumnOrder> Order { get; set; }
        public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    }

    public class Search
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Regex { get; set; }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Searchable { get; set; }
        public bool Orderable { get; set; }
        public Search Search { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColumnOrder
    {
        public int Column { get; set; }
        public string Dir { get; set; }
    }
```

**RESULT ON BUILD AND RUN:**
[image: Stuck on 'processing...']

**As you can see I am stuck on processing. What could be the issue?**

**WHEN I DEBUG, YOU CAN SEE THAT DRAW IS = 1:**
[image]
[image]

**When I explicitly assign draw to 1, I get a message that there is no data in the table:**
[image]

**url: "/Home/Data?start=0&&length=10"** returns no data:
[image: /Home/Data?start=0&&length=10]

**Here is the `Length` and `Start` when debug:**
[image]

**query:**
[image: query]

**result:**
[image: result]

**pureData:**
[image: pureData]

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to make sure `Draw` cannot be 0,when it is 0,you will stuck on 'processing...'.

2.In your code,I find

```
return Ok(new { tableParams.Draw, recordsTotal = totalCount, recordsFiltered = result.Select(c => c.Count).FirstOrDefault(), data = pureData });
```

and `recordsFiltered` type should be integer.
Here is [an official link](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) about the parameters.

3.In your view:

you need to change

```
columns: [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "firstname" },
                { data: "lastname" },
                { data: "country" },
                { data: "gender" },
                { data: "age" }
            ]
```

to

```
columns: [
                    { data: "id" },
                    { data: "firstName" },
                    { data: "lastName" },
                    { data: "country" },
                    { data: "gender" },
                    { data: "age" }
                ]
```

Or the FirstName and LastName will not be binded.

Here is a working demo with fake data to test:

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Data(DataTablesResult tableParams)
        {
            
            List<Users> users = new List<Users> { new Users { Id = "1", Age = "1", Country = "UK", Gender = "Male", FirstName = "A", LastName = "A" },
                new Users { Id = "2", Age = "2", Country = "UK", Gender = "Male", FirstName = "B", LastName = "B" },
                new Users { Id = "3", Age = "3", Country = "UK", Gender = "Male", FirstName = "C", LastName = "C" } };
            return Ok(new { Draw = 1, recordsTotal = 10, recordsFiltered = users.Count(), data = users});
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223121/discussion-on-answer-by-yiyi-you-datatable-version-1-10-21-is-stuck-on-processi).

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue by adding a `JsonSerializer` to my `Startup.cs` class. It was the single line of `code` I was missing.

I have posted the solution here:
[Datatables server-side processing in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292529/datatables-server-side-processing-in-asp-net-core-3-1/64384762#64384762)