# Jquery datatable, server side search filter and asc/desc order with ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application, where I have implemented listing with jQuery datatable.

Here is example for jQuery implementation; I want to enable server side searching and asc/desc ordering; pagination is working fine.

If you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
<table id="vendor-list" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Vendor Code</th>
            <th>Vendor name</th>
            <th>Vendor Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Vendor Code</th>
            <th>Vendor name</th>
            <th>Vendor Email</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

var dtable = $('#vendor-list').DataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        searchDelay: 500,
        serverSide: true,
        searching: true,
        filter:true,
        stateSave: true,
        paging: true,
        processing: true,
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
        "filter": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: '/admin/vendor/get-vendor-list/',
            type: 'GET',
            "beforeSend": function () {
                //TableLoading(true);
            },
            "complete": function () {
                //TableLoading(false);
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                "data": "vendorCode"
            },
            { "data": "vendorName" },
            { "data": "vendorEmail" }
            
        ]
    });

    $(".dataTables_filter input")
        .unbind() // Unbind previous default bindings
        .bind("input", function (e) { // Bind our desired behavior
            // If the length is 3 or more characters, or the user pressed ENTER, search
            if (this.value.length >= 3 || e.keyCode == 13) {
                // Call the API search function
                dtable.search(this.value).draw();
            }
            // Ensure we clear the search if they backspace far enough
            if (this.value == "") {
                dtable.search("").draw();
            }
            return;
        });
```

In the backend, implementation is like

```
public class JqueryDatatableParamRequestModel
{
    public int Draw { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public DataTableOrder[] Order { get; set; }
    public DataTableColumn[] Columns { get; set; }

    public int RecordPerPage { get; set; }   
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public DataTableSearch Search { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableSearch
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableOrder
{
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableColumn
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Searchable { get; set; }
    public bool Orderable { get; set; }

    public DataTableSearch Search { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller action method is like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetVendorList(JqueryDatatableParamRequestModel request)
{
        VendorListQuery vendorListQuery = new VendorListQuery();
        vendorListQuery.PageNumber = request.Length * (request.Start / request.Length) + 1;
        vendorListQuery.RecordPerPage = request.Length;
        GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse(false);
        var result = await _vendorService.GetVendorList(vendorListQuery);
        return Json(new DataTableResponse { draw = request.Draw, recordsTotal = result.SuccessValue.FirstOrDefault().Count, data = result.SuccessValue.ToArray(), error = "", recordsFiltered = result.SuccessValue.FirstOrDefault().Count });
}
```

Request values are mentioned as below when I call the action method:

[image]

Is there any alternate way to achieve this? It doesn't matter if we add one extra control, like dropbox(select) which contains column name, and according selected values, we can search/filter records?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996638/how-to-implement-datatables-server-side-side-paging-searching-sorting-in-asp-net) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292529/datatables-server-side-processing-in-asp-net-core-3-1) ,  refer them to enable server side searching and asc/desc ordering.

Comment: @QingGuo thanks for your help, I need more help, so when I read data from Request.Query["search[value]"], It gives me search value key, so is it possible that we can add a dropdown/select control which contains list of table column, so use select column and type in to search textfield, and at server end I can get search field column, so it would be help full.?

Comment: @QingGuo So basically Request.Query["search[value]"], I don't have any idea which column needs to refer (WITHOUT IMPLEMENTING ANY COMPLEX LOGIC IN EFCORE LINQ)